# Pandas - Assertion Error aggregating with max

Tags: pandas

I have been doing this series of aggregations for months now, with no error whatsoever.

```
goals = df.groupby('name').sum()['G']
assists = df.groupby('name').sum()['A']
shots_post = df.groupby('name').sum()['FT']
shots_saved = df.groupby('name').sum()['FD']
shots_off = df.groupby('name').sum()['FF']

home = df.groupby('name')['home_dummy'].agg(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
position = df.groupby('name')['position'].agg(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
team = df.groupby('name')['club'].agg(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
games = df.groupby('name').max()['games_num']
```

Now, with no `pandas` upgrade/downgrade at all, this last line (and only this one):

```
games = df.groupby('name').max()['games_num']
```

Suddenly began to break, throwing the following error:

```
    games = df.groupby('name').max()['games_num']
packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1100, in _cython_agg_blocks
    assert len(locs) == result.shape[1]
AssertionError
```

---

What might have happened? Is there another way of grouping games using the code above?

Comment: ```df.groupby('name')['games_num'].max()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem should be some column is not numeric, solution is specified column after `groupby`:

```
games = df.groupby('name')['games_num'].max()
```

Another idea is convert column to numeric:

```
df['games_num'] = pd.to_numeric)df['games_num'], errors='coerce')
games = df.groupby('name')['games_num'].max()
```

---

Instead all groupby here should be possible use names aggregation with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0]
df1 = df.groupby('name').agg(goals=('G','sum'),
                             assists=('A', 'sum'),
                             shots_post=('FT', 'sum'),
                             shots_saved=('FD', 'sum'),
                             shots_off=('FF', 'sum'),
                             home=('home_dummy', f),
                             position=('position', f),
                             team=('club', f),
                             games=('games_num', 'max')
                             )
```